# get a value out of a function?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

I am trying to get value out of java script function to a variable

```
var isMember;

                        IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Team Management System Members", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
                            if (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
                                //alert("Admin");
                                isMember = true;
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                isMember = false;
                                //alert("NoAdmin")
                            }
                        });

                        alert(isMember);
```

the other function used to be called

```
 function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {

                        var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

                        var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
                        currentContext.load(currentUser);

                        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
                        currentContext.load(allGroups);

                        var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
                        currentContext.load(group);

                        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
                        currentContext.load(groupUsers);

                        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFailure);

                        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
                            var userInGroup = false;
                            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
                            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
                                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                                    userInGroup = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            OnComplete(userInGroup);
                        }

                        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
                            OnComplete(false);
                        }
                    }
```

but when I execute i am getting the value : undefined

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not related to `isMember` because it's already defined outside of all functions so it's in the global scope. so make sure that `isCurrentUserInGroup` is already defined.

Meanwhile, To know which variable specifically is undefined try to use `F12 developer` tools to check the error in console tab.

**Note:** Do NOT create global variables unless you intend to.In "Strict Mode" automatically global variables will fail. for more details check [JavaScript Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

U can use an auxiliar function

```
IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Team Management System Members", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
        if (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
            //alert("Admin");
            isMember = true;
        }
        else {
            isMember = false;
            //alert("NoAdmin")
        }
        newFunction(isMember);
    })

    function newFunction(param) {
        console.log(param)
    }
```

Can you remove that `return true` from the `if`. In fact, you should return just the `isCurrentUserInGroup` var, that var is already a bool.
I test your code it work just fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/wwh7eroa/

Comment: i got undefined

Comment: answer improved

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to do something fundamentally impossible: access a value in a synchronous context which is not yet available because it's set asynchronously. Have a look at my comments:

```
var isMember;

IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Team Management System Members", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    isMember = isCurrentUserInGroup; //Executed AFTER the alert
});

alert(isMember); //This line is executed BEFORE the the value is set (hence undefined)
```

Now, I think you need to understand this concept and re-write your code appropriately. Move your 'alert' - or whatever - into the function where isCurrentUserInGroup is available.